# celery and long running tasks

Tags: python, celery

I just watch [a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cyq5DHjymw) where the presenter mentioned that one should design his/her celery to be short. Tasks running several minutes are bad.

Is this correct? What I do see is that I have some long running task, which takes say 10 minutes to finish. When these kind of task is scheduled frequently, the queue is swamped and no other tasks get scheduled. Is this the reason?

If so, what should be used for long running tasks?

Answer (score 10):

Long running tasks aren't great but It's by no means appropriate to say they are bad.  The best way to handle long running tasks is to create a queue for just those tasks and have them run on a separate worker then the short tasks.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with long running tasks is that you have to wait for them when you're pushing a new software version on your server. If you don't wait, your task may run possibly incompatible code, especially if you pickled some complex object as a parameter (which is strongly discouraged).

Answer (score 4):

As @user2097159 said its a good practice to keep the long running tasks in a dedicate queue. You should do that by routing using "settings.CELERY_ROUTES" [more info here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html)

If you could estimate how long a task can be running, I recommend to use [soft_time_limit](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.soft_time_limit) per task, you will be able to handle it.

There is a gist from a talk I gave [here](https://gist.github.com/malderete/40ffa8b8f16431f55ca8#file-pyconar2014-py-L150)

Answer (score 3):

Augment the basic `Task` definition to optionally treat the task instantiation as a generator, and check for TERM or soft timeout on every iteration through the generator.  Generically inject a "state" dict kwarg into tasks that support it.  If it's the first time the task is run, allocate a new one in results cache, otherwise look up the existing one from results cache.

In your task, figure out a good place to yield which results in short execution times.  Update the `state` parameter as necessary.

When control returns to the master task class, check for TERM or soft timeout, and if there is one, save off the `state` object and respond to the signal.