Celery with redis doesn't seem to honor visibility_timeout
We want stalled tasks to be picked up by a new worker so we're using task_acks_late: True along with visibility_timeout. Some of the tasks can take a pretty long time to run so we attempted to update the visibility_timeout.
Celery settings are as follows:
            "broker_url": "redis://app-redis:6379/0",
            "result_backend": "redis://app-redis:6379/0",
            "worker_send_task_events": True,
            "task_serializer": "pickle",
            "result_serializer": "pickle",
            "accept_content": ["pickle"],
            "task_acks_late": True,
            "task_reject_on_worker_lost": True,
            "worker_prefetch_multiplier": 1,
            "broker_transport_options": {"visibility_timeout": 3600},
            "result_backend_transport_options": {"visibility_timeout": 3600},
            "visibility_timeout": 3600,
            "worker_max_memory_per_child": 200000,
            "redis_socket_keepalive": True,
            "task_routes": {"apps.worker.batch_tasks.*": {"queue": "batch_tasks"}}

We're using Celery 5.3.6.
Looking at the logs, even with "broker_transport_options": {"visibility_timeout": 3600}, "result_backend_transport_options": {"visibility_timeout": 3600}, "visibility_timeout": 3600, tasks are still getting requeued every ~20 minutes. (The tasks aren't failing, they're just taking a long time. They'd probably complete in 30-35 minutes. They are being submitted to the default queue, not the batch_tasks queue.)
Am I missing an addition setting? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5935  ,  https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/7651 Is this the same type of issue you are facing?

More for ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31711907/9075457

Those links are definitely related, but there's no conclusive solution. I can try playing with the soft timeout I suppose.

I would suggest kindly raise the issue in "celery" Libera Chat with channel name #celery or raise the issue as bug on github.
